# Better than O(log(N)) base 2

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, time-complexity, segment-tree

I am solving Segment tree and Quad Tree related problems; while I noticed that in segment tree we split the 1D array into **2 (2^1)** segments and recursively do this until base case arrives. Similarly, in Quad tree We subdivide the 2D grid into **4 (2^2)** segments in every step. All these divide-and-Conquer mechanism is for achieving logarithmic time complexity. No offense!

But why don't we subdivide the array into **4 (4^1)** parts or more instead of 2 parts in segment tree? And why we don't split the grid into **16 (4^2)** parts instead of 4? By doing these, We can achieve `O(log(N))` performance, but it would be a better `log` as `log(N)`(base 4) is better than `log(N)`(base 2).

I know in this case, the implementation would be little bit difficult. Is there a memory overhead problem? Or anything?

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Changing the base of the logarithms used doesn't alter calculations of computational complexity.  Think of how you change the base of logarithms. You use a multiplier of `1/log_newbase(old_base)` which is, essentially,  the same as a constant multiplier in an expression such as `O(k*n^2)`. Computational complexity ignores such factors, though programmers are often well-advised to pay serious attention to them.

Comment: Going from `log2` to `log4` cuts the number of steps in half, but each step is typically around `log2(4)=2` times as much work, so there is no net gain. It does turn out to be a net win if the work within a step is much lower than the cost of taking a step. Data structures like B-trees use a high branching factor for this reason.

Comment: This is not a programming question; it is theoretical. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's also basically a duplicate of [Time complexity using N way merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420397/time-complexity-using-n-way-merge/10420565).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't actually work faster. Let's assume that we divided it into 4 parts. Then we would have to merge 4 values instead of 2 in each node to answer the query. Assuming that merging 4 values takes 3 times longer(for example, to get the maximum of 2 numbers we need 1 call to max function, but to get the maximum of 4 values 3 calls are required), we have log4(n) * 3 > log2(n) * 1. Moreover, it would be harder to implement(more cases to be considered and so on).

Comment: See [Fusion Tree (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_tree). I'm thinking you can do something similar with parallel processing, with P processors giving O(log_P(N)) performance, it's probably also practical with [GPGPU programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU). Though as mentioned here before, if it's done with a single processor then it typically ends up speeding things up in one area just to slow it down in another.

Answer (score 1):

log 4 (N) = log 2 (N) / log 2 (4) =  log 2 (N) / 2

in general,the time complexity are both O(logn) , while four segments is much harder than two segments to maintain. In fact ，（In acm/icpc） two segments are much easy to code and it is suffcient to work.